# How to calculate a 95% Credible Interval for a Bernouli sampling in R?

Tags: r, bayesian, credible-interval

How does one calculate a 95% Credible Interval for Bernouli sampling?
I have looked into the package emdbook and the function tcredint() but i am unsure if this the way to go.

If anyone has references, I'm grateful.

**Create data with 2000 rows of (0,1)**
set.seed(100)
data<-data.frame(replicate(1,sample(0:1,2000,replace=TRUE)))
colnames(data) <- c("sample")
require(psych)
mean(data$sample)
sd(data$sample)'

**Confidence Interval**
require(Publish) 
ci.mean(data)]

**Credible Interval**
install.packages("gmodels")
require(gmodels)
require(stats)
p=pbeta(data$sample, shape1=2, shape2=2, ncp = 0, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)
ci(p)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, you've not supplied enough information to answer as we'd need to know your prior.

However, I will assume you're looking at a $p\sim$Beta$(\alpha, \alpha)$ prior. In that case, if you have $N$ trials with a total of $Y$ successes the posterior distribution is $p | \mathcal D \sim$Beta$(\alpha + N - Y, \alpha + Y)$.

You can use the distribution function for Beta to calculate the necessary tails using those parameters.

Comment: My prior is πθ~ß(a,b). From what I am working with, it looks like I am using a Beta-Binomial posterior distribution (π(θ/y) ~ ß (y+a,n–y+b)). So, my best bet is the pbeta function in R?

Comment: Yup. One detail 'Beta-Binomial' also refers to the predictive distribution for a new set of trials. You're just intereseted in the Beta posterior on the parameter.

Comment: When i used the function pbeta, the credible intervals' lower and upper bound is identical to the confidence interval. Is my R script above accurate? I'm assuming that the reason is because of my Shape1 and Shape2 parameters.

Comment: Are you adding in the prior alpha and beta to the conjugate beta posterior shape parameters?

Comment: I don't think I did unless the function, p=pbeta(data$sample, shape1=2, shape2=2, ncp = 0, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE), did it for me. Is there an R script that I would need to do before calculating the pbeta?

Comment: @BryanMac it's literally as simple as adding some number(s) $\alpha, \beta >0$ to your shape parameters. What you've probably found is that as $\alpha, \beta \rightarrow 0$ that the frequentist and Bayesian methods provide the same answer (at least, this is often the case - I've not worked it out).